# how to improve the ifelse() function with large dataset that doesn't work in R

Tags: r

I have a large dataset `metdata` with 505153 obs. and 119 variables. I use the following function to replace all the values in `SWC_` columns (e.g. SWC_11, SWC_21, SWC_31...) taht are lower than zero with NA. But the codes that I wrote (see below) take R forever to get the result. The codes themselves are correct, but just took tons of time. I was wondering if there is any good suggestion to revise my codes.

```
metdata<- ifelse( metdata[, grep("SWC_",names(metdata))]<0, NA,metdata[, grep("SWC_",names(metdata))]) 
 metdata<- as.data.frame(metdata) #it takes forever.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A direct assignment without the use of `ifelse` should be faster.

```
cols <- grep("SWC_",names(metdata))
metdata[cols][metdata[cols] < 0] <- NA
metdata

#  id    SWC_11    SWC_22
#1  1        NA 0.4688236
#2  2 0.8920381 0.7989282
#3  3        NA 0.8350749
#4  4 1.5655875        NA
#5  5        NA 0.3890191
```

**data**

```
set.seed(3415)
metdata <- data.frame(id = 1:5, SWC_11 = rnorm(5), SWC_22 = rnorm(5))
metdata
#  id     SWC_11     SWC_22
#1  1 -1.0583887  0.4688236
#2  2  0.8920381  0.7989282
#3  3 -1.2087020  0.8350749
#4  4  1.5655875 -0.7899368
#5  5 -1.9995943  0.3890191
```

Answer (score 0):

Demonstrative example using the `iris` dataset:

```
testiris <- iris
testiris[,startsWith(names(testiris), "Sepal")][testiris[,startsWith(names(testiris), "Sepal")] < 6] <- NA
```

Reasoning:
`names(testiris)` returns `"Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width"  "Species"` 
`startsWith(names(testiris), "Sepal")` returns `TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

This can then be used to select columns from the data set.
You can repeat that column selection then test for your condition (in my example, `< 6`) to select the elements within the columns.
`<- NA` assigns the value NA.